# Grant Alter to Only to All Functions on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

Need help to GRANT ALTER only to all the SQL Server Functions.

Below is mycode:

```sql
    GRANT ALTER ON FUNCTION::dbo TO [username]
```

Comment: So what is the "help" you need..?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions), `ALTER FUNCTION` requires ALTER permission on the function itself or the schema. You can't grant ALTER on all functions without allowing ALTER on other objects.

You should set up a role with the required permissions and then add users to that role.

```
CREATE ROLE edit_functions AUTHORIZATION [db_owner];

ALTER ROLE edit_functions ADD MEMBER [username];

GRANT ALTER ON [schema].[function1] TO edit_functions;
GRANT ALTER ON [schema].[function2] TO edit_functions;
```

etc.

If you edit the role properties in SSMS, the "securables" page allows you to search for "all objects of the types..." and you can pick the types for functions.

[image: SSMS Add Objects dialog]